# Sidebar menu not full height

Tags: html, css, menu, sidebar

I've a problem with my Menu, I don't know how to fix this. It needs to get the full height of your screen but I can't fix it.

Here is my **CSS** code.

```
nav{
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: -25px 0px 60px #00000033;
}

html body nav div#nav-inner{
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin: -10px;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle with my problem:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c6vgmd9/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: `100vh` means 100% of the viewports height.

Comment: use position:fixed along with height:100%

Answer (score 0):

First you need wrapper div inside body:

```
<body>
   <div class="wrapper"><!--added-->
       <nav>...</nav>
       <div id="container">...</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

With CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Next you need to change **#container** div "**position:absolute**" to "**position:relative**"

and finally:

```
nav{ 
    height: 100% 
}
```

On this way. You will have relative .wrapper with height of your page content and  with full height of this content :)